# Prove $var ( \Theta) = var(\hat \Theta) + var(\tilde \Theta)$ using the law of total variance

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, bayesian

I am watching a lecture on Bayesian inference where the professor says this formula $(*)$ can be derived using **the law of total variance** but the derivation is not done in the lecture.

https://youtu.be/XtNXQJkgkhI?t=1812

$$var ( \Theta) = var(\hat \Theta) + var(\tilde \Theta) \tag{*}$$

So how can that be done?

**Definitions:**

a) $\Theta$ is an unknown parameter (r.v.) which we're trying to estimate

b) $\hat \Theta$ is the optimal LMS estimation of that unknown parameter $\hat{\Theta} := \mathbb{E}[\Theta \: | \: X]$

c) $\tilde \Theta$ is the error in the estimation of that unknown parameter i.e. $\tilde \Theta := \hat \Theta - \Theta$

I am looking at the law of total variance and I just don't see (yet) how to prove this formula by using it i.e. I don't see how it's related to $(*)$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance

Any hints/ideas?

Comment: No idea why this question got downvoted.

Comment: Maybe the reason to the downvotes is, that people prefer that all the details are contained in the question itself and not through links to other sources (youtube videos and such). You could easily have filled in the details of what $\hat{\Theta}$ and $\tilde{\Theta}$ are.

Comment: @LeanderTilstedKristensen Oh... I thought $\hat \Theta$ and $\tilde \Theta$ are standard notations in the field of Bayesian inference. That's why I didn't define them. Thanks again for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is mentioned in the lecture slides, that $Cov(\hat{\Theta},\tilde{\Theta})=0$, and from this it easily follows, that
$$Var(\Theta)=Var(\hat{\Theta}+\tilde{\Theta})=Var(\hat{\Theta})+Var(\tilde{\Theta}) + 2\underbrace{Cov(\hat{\Theta},\tilde{\Theta})}_{=0}.$$
But this doesn't really show the relation to the law of total variance. From the lecture slides $\hat{\Theta}$ is introduced as
$$\hat{\Theta} := \mathbb{E}[\Theta \: | \: X],$$
so
$$Var(\hat{\Theta}) = Var(\mathbb{E}[\Theta \: | \: X]),$$
and thus the missing piece in order to relate the formula to the law of total variance is to show, that
$$Var(\tilde{\Theta}) = \mathbb{E}(Var(\Theta \: | \: X)).$$
I will now argue that this is indeed the case:
\begin{align*}
Var(\tilde{\Theta})&=Var(-\tilde{\Theta}) \\
&= Var(\Theta - \mathbb{E}[\Theta \: | \: X]) \\
&= \mathbb{E}[(\Theta-\mathbb{E}[\Theta \: | \: X])^2] &\text{(since $\mathbb{E}[\tilde{\Theta}] = 0$)} \\
&= \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[(\Theta-\mathbb{E}[\Theta \: | \: X])^2 \: | \: X]] & \text{(Law of total expectation)} \\
&= \mathbb{E}[Var(\Theta \: | \: X)] &\text{(by definition of conditional variance)}
\end{align*}